# How to convert a char array to a string array

Tags: java, type-conversion

How do you convert a char array to a string array? Or better yet, can you take a string and convert it to a string array that contains each character of the string?

Edit: thanks @Emiam! Used his code as a temp array then used another array to get rid of the extra space and it works perfectly:

```
String[] tempStrings = Ext.split("");
String[] mStrings = new String[Ext.length()];

for (int i = 0; i < Ext.length(); i++) 
    mStrings[i] = tempStrings[i + 1];
```

Comment: do you mean array of char arrays?

Comment: `string.toCharArray()` and `new String(chararray)`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> Or better yet, can you take a string and convert it to a string array
>   that contains each character of the string?

I think this can be done by splitting the string at "". Like this:

```
String [] myarray = mystring.split("");
```

Edit:
In case you don't want the leading empty string, you would use the regex: "(?!^)"

```
String [] mySecondArray = mystring.split("(?!^)");
```

Comment: you actually get a bit of weirdness if you do .split("") as there an empty string at the beginning of the string (or it's something like that) either way the output has a empty zero length string in position 0 myarray

Comment: Well yes, but if that's the case, one could just create another array without the first element.

Comment: Thanks, this works but does add the extra empty character at the beginning. I can work with this though

Answer (score 7):

Beautiful Java 8 one-liner for people in the future:

```
String[] array = Stream.of(charArray).map(String::valueOf).toArray(String[]::new);
```

Comment: won't work for me, I'm getting an ArrayStoreException

Comment: @kopaka that‘s weird, it worked for me. Could you show me your code?

Comment: ```char [] regKey = {'A','B','C','D'}; 
        String[] array = Stream.of(regKey).toArray(String[]::new);``` leads to an ArrayStoreException

Comment: This isn't a good solution, it merges all of the characters into one string.

Answer (score 3):

I have made the following test to check Emiam's assumption:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "abcdef";

    String [] array = str.split("");
}
```

It works, but it adds an empty string in position 0 of the array.
So array is 7 characters long and is { "", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f" }.

I have made this test with Java SE 1.6.

Comment: how can I remove "" fro the array.   I need only {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f" }.   Any possibility?

Comment: @CHAKRAVARTHI This is not a dynamic array, so you have to create a new array with the slots you would like to keep. This can be done plenty of ways. If it is just a matter of skipping the first "", it is maybe better to index the array a 1-based way instead of a 0-based way.

Answer (score 2):

brute force:

```
String input = "yourstring";
int len = input.length();
String [] result = new String[len];

for(int i = 0; i < len ; i ++ ){
    result[i] = input.substring(i,i+1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give string[] as result, but will have only one value as below
String[] str = {"abcdef"};

Answer (score 0):

// char[] to String[]
    String[] sa1 = String.valueOf(cArray).split("");